# swift cast from AnyHashable to enum

Tags: swift, enums, casting, option-type, unwrap

I have this playground:

```
import Foundation

enum WeekDay: Int {
    case mon, tues, wed, thurs, fri, sat, sun
}

let wd = WeekDay(rawValue: 0)! // mon

let param = [wd: [1, 2, 3]]
message(dict: param)

func message(dict: [AnyHashable: [Int]?]) {
    for (k, v) in dict {
        print(k, type(of: k), v) // mon AnyHashable Optional([1, 2, 3])

        if let k = k as? WeekDay {
            print("got it: \(k)")
        }
    }
}
```

But I can never get `got it: ...` printed.

Why can't I cast from an `AnyHashable` to `WeekDay`?

The reason I want to use `AnyHashable` in function `message` is that the key of `dict` can be `Int` or `WeekDay`. If I don't use `AnyHashable`, what type should I use for my purpose?

Thanks

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7049

Comment: You should define your own `protocol` instead of using `AnyHashable`.  `protocol WeekDayOrInt` `extension WeekDay: WeekDayOrInt { }` `extension Int: WeekDayOrInt { }`  `var dict = [WeekDayOrInt : [Int]]()`.  Then those two types and only those two types can be used as keys for your dict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `base` value of `AnyHashable` to cast back to its original type as below,

```
if let k = (k.base as? WeekDay), k == .mon {
   print("got it: \(k)")
}
```